# How to assign user an application role in azure active directory using graph api 1.5?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I had faced an issue on adding user an application role in azure active directory.
In User model,there is a property called ApproleAssignment where i think i can set an application role for the user.But when i had done that,its not assigning.Can anyone help me?

I added application roles using App roles in application model.And i can populate through drop down when creating a user.Below shows the section of creating user.
What should be given as ResourceId in AppRoleAssignment?

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(UserModel user)
        {
            ActiveDirectoryClient client = null;
            try
            {
                client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (Request.QueryString["reauth"] == "True")
                {
                    //
                    // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request to get a new set of tokens.
                    // If the user still has a valid session with Azure AD, they will not be prompted for their credentials.
                    // The OpenID Connect middleware will return to this controller after the sign-in response has been handled.
                    //
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                        .Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                }

                //
                // The user needs to re-authorize.  Show them a message to that effect.
                //
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "AuthorizationRequired";
                return View();
            }

            try
            {
                User mappedUser = MapToUser(user);
                await client.Users.AddUserAsync(mappedUser);
                await AddUserRole(mappedUser, user);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", exception.Message);
                return View();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds the user role.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mappedUser">The mapped user.</param>
        /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task AddUserRole(User mappedUser, UserModel model)
        {
            ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
            IPagedCollection<IUser> pagedCollection = await client.Users.ExecuteAsync();
            var currentUser = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.Where(x => x.UserPrincipalName.Equals(mappedUser.UserPrincipalName)).FirstOrDefault();
            var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment();
            appRoleAssignment.Id = model.AppRoleId;
            appRoleAssignment.PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(currentUser.ObjectId);
            appRoleAssignment.ResourceId = Guid.Parse(clientId);
            ////((ClaimsIdentity)ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity).AddClaim(
            ////    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Manager", ClaimValueTypes.String, "GRAPH"));
            await currentUser.UpdateAsync();
            ////Remaining have to be completed.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Maps to user.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model">The model.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User MapToUser(UserModel model)
        {
            var user = new User();
            user.UserPrincipalName = model.UserPrincipalName;
            user.AccountEnabled = model.AccountEnabled;
            user.PasswordProfile = model.PasswordProfile;
            user.MailNickname = model.MailNickname;
            user.DisplayName = model.DisplayName;
            user.GivenName = model.GivenName;
            user.Surname = model.Surname;
            user.JobTitle = model.JobTitle;
            user.Department = model.Department;

            return user;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry I'm struggling to follow your code, because some of it is missing (like your definition of the application and any application roles it declares).  At a high level, an application would define a series of application roles (appRoles). Once a user consents to the app, an app instance representing the application will be present in the consenting tenant.  If you want to assign a user to that application, in one of the specified app roles, you'll need to set the appRoleAssignment on the user (picking the app role id, and the resource id - the application's id). appRoleAssignment and its properties are described here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn835128.aspx and the REST API examples described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2014/12/12/announcing-the-new-version-of-graph-api-api-version-1-5.aspx.

Also we have a console sample that shows both appRole creation on an application, and assignment of the application (in the declared app role) to a user.  You can find that on github here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet

HTHs,

Comment: This sample is one file of code which is hard to follow. Is there a dedicated fewliner example which shows how to add an existing user to an existing application role?

Answer (score 1):

The resource ID you have in your code is the wrong one:

```
appRoleAssignment.ResourceId = Guid.Parse(clientId);
```

The resource that the graph app uses is the ID of the *service principle* associated with the application. You can read about the difference between applications and service principles [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-objects/), but briefly the clientID is the ID of the application *definition* whereas the service principle, as I understand it, is an active instance of it. So the ID you need is the *objectID* of the service principle making the role assignment. Some test code to get the service principle ID would be like this:

```
var servicePrincipleList = await client.ServicePrincipals.Where(e => e.AppId == clientId).ExecuteAsync();

var roleResourceUpdateID = servicePrincipleList.CurrentPage.First().ObjectId;
```

and that is the Object ID you need to use in your role assignment.